# when spawning threads, how do I throttle the maximum number possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

How do I spawn threads to the maximum number possible assuming that each thread may take different time to complete. The idea is to spawn the maximum number of threads possible while not causing any to die.

E.g. While (spawnable) spawn more threads;

I am trying to spawn threads to make calls to ejb, I wish to spawn the maximum number possible to simulate a load while not causing the threads to go into out of memory exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Executor framework has been cited here, and it's a wonderful tool indeed (Already +1'ed that answer).

But I believe what the OP wants is a [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29).

From the docs:

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will
>   reuse previously constructed threads when they are available

More on executors [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Answer (score 6):

[Executors.newFixedThreadPool()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) or for finer control, create your own [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Will using any of the two api help to size the pool according to the needs or do I specify the numbers?

Comment: @Chin: Take a look at the [docs for ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Specifically: "A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize())."

Answer (score 2):

There is no fixed answer. You need to tune the number of threads to your host capabilities.

In response to the memory issue, it is not only a matter of how many threads are there but also of what they do. It is not the same if they perform simple calls or have to deal with huge arrays.

Relative for performance, and supposing that your host is dedicated, a value of one thread per core is a minimum value. Given that they are going to call a remote system most of these threads will spend a time idle; depending of the proportion of idle time you can spawn more or less.

In essence, chech your host performance and tune your thread number in consequence.